# Remove common list elements in lists of lists in R

Tags: r, list, set-difference

I have a list of lists, I would like to remove the common elements between these sublists.

For example

```
mylist = list(
c(1, 2, 3, 4),
c(2, 5, 6, 7),
c(4, 2, 8, 9)
)
```

becomes

```
mylist = list(
c(1, 3),
c(5, 6, 7),
c(8, 9)
)
```

I first created a list of the common elements and tried to substrate this list from the sublist but it does not work

```
common_elements = list(Reduce(intersect, mylist))
mylist = mylist[!(mylist %in% common_elements)]
```

Could you help me ? Thank you !

Comment: I modified the syntax, thank you

Answer (score 2):

A base R option

```
> lut <- table(unlist(mylist))

> comm <- as.numeric(names(lut[lut > 1]))

> lapply(mylist, function(x) x[!x %in% comm])
[[1]]
[1] 1 3

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7

[[3]]
[1] 8 9
```

## data

```
mylist <- list(1:4, c(2, 5:7), c(4, 2, 8, 9))
```

Comment: Thank you
Could you explain me why
mylist = mylist[!(mylist %in% common_elements)] does not work ?

Comment: @Vesperal `common_elements` is a list with value `2` only, `mylist` is a list of vectors, while none of the vectors is exactly the same of `2`, thus `%in%` will return false when you apply `mylist %in% common_elements`.

Comment: Understood thank you !

Comment: If the vectors contained characters like "tata" "titi" "tata" instead of numbers, how would I modify the code ?

Comment: @Vesperal then you remove `as.numeric`

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse option for a list of lists.

```
library(tidyverse)

ls %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  mutate(dupes = if_else(duplicated(value) == T, as.integer(value), NA_integer_)) %>%
  filter(!value %in% dupes) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(X = list(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(X) %>%
  deframe()

# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] 3
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 5
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] 6
# 
# [[2]][[3]]
# [1] 7
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]][[1]]
# [1] 8
# 
# [[3]][[2]]
# [1] 9
```

Data

```
ls <- list(list(1, 2, 3, 4), list(2, 5, 6, 7), list(4, 2, 8, 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the update, it is a `list` of `vector`s.  Convert the `list` to a two column tibble/data.frame with `enframe`, get the count of distinct elements to `filter` and `split` back to a `list` of `vector`s

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
enframe(mylist) %>%     
    unnest(value) %>%
    group_by(value) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(name) == 1) %>% 
    with(., split(value, name)) %>%
    unname
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 3

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7

[[3]]
[1] 8 9
```

#### data

```
mylist <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(2, 5, 6, 7), c(4, 2, 8, 9))
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that